# Viewing Debug Log for a class

Tags: class, developer-console, debugging

I just created this simple class:

```
    global class HelloSandboxWorld implements SandboxPostCopy {
  global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
      System.debug('Hello Tester Pester ' + context.organizationId() + ' ' + context.sandboxId() + context.sandboxName());
    }
  }
```

Now I want to debug it, I opened an anonymous execution window and typed the following:

```
HelloSandboxWorld s = new HelloSandboxWorld();
```

I executed the code, opened the logs, but nothing appears under 'Debug'.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it easiest to Debug this class from a Test class.

E.g.

```
@isTest
public class HelloSandboxWorld_test {

    @isTest
    public static void testPostCopy(){
        // The ID's from these Accounts will standin for the actual Orgs 
        // as we can't create those   
        Account sandbox = new Account(
            Name = 'sandbox'
        );

        insert sandbox;

        Test.startTest();

        Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript(
            new SandboxDataProvider(), 
            UserInfo.getOrganizationId(), 
            sandbox.Id, 
            'TestSandboxName'
        );      

        Test.stopTest();   
    }
}
```

You can capture the Debug log as usual when the test case is run.

Answer (score 0):

Call the runApexClass function with the instance variable of your class.

Eg:-

```
HelloSandboxWorld s = new HelloSandboxWorld();
SandboxContext context = new SandboxContext();
s.runApexClass(context);
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, got the following error: Type cannot be constructed: SandboxContext

Comment: Can you add more code here? That is just an example not actual working code